# My proof of convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution

Tags: probability

When I tried to prove the direction, $P(X\leq x)\leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}P(X_{n}\leq x)$, I didn't use continuity of $F(x)$.

Here's my proof

> $$
> P(X\leq x)=P(X_{n}\leq x, |X_{n}-X|> \epsilon)+P(X_{n}\leq x, |X_{n}-X|\leq \epsilon)\\\leq P(|X_{n}-X|> \epsilon)+P(X_{n}\leq X+\epsilon)
> $$
>
> Take liminf of both sides,by convergence in probability, we have
>
> $$P(X\leq x)\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty}P(X_{n}\leq x+\epsilon) \tag1$$
>
> Then let $\epsilon \to 0$, we get $$P(X\leq x)\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty}P(X_{n}\leq x)$$

The proof in the book is almost the same as mine, but it begin with $P(X\leq x-\epsilon)$ and its equation $(1)$ is $$P(X\leq x-\epsilon)\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty}P(X_{n}\leq X)$$which uses continuity of $F$ when it lets $\epsilon \to 0$
. I want to know what's wrong with my proof.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the final limit of $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ that you are taking that is wrong. To see it, you can test it with $ X_n = 1/n $ w.p. 1 and $X = 0$ w.p. 1, and take little $x$ to be 0. (1) is correct for all $\epsilon$, but since you cannot bring the limit inside without a notion of continuity, the second inequality does not follow and is indeed false.

Comment: Suppose the distribution functions of $X_{n}$ are continuous, then is my proof valid?

Comment: I don't think continuity itself will be enough, since you can always make a continuous function that is 1 on [1/n, \infty) and 0 on (-\infty, 0] for each n and the example above goes through.